# Find revision and report the step number where the revision occurs

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a code that will find revisions in a Word document, and report the revision and number from the list (the step number) in a separate table (which is already set up and good to go). (See the attached picture). So for example, any revision in row 3 will report step number 10.1. So what I was thinking was that for each revision it would go to the HOME cell on the row where the step number is located (and then if there is none it moves up to find one). That worked fine when there wasn't any revisions and I just placed the cursor in random cells. I think what's wrong with my code is that it's not placing the cursor at the revision, so having code moving the cursor to the beginning row doesn't do anything. 
I tried changing 
stepnumber = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString 
to 
stepnumber = oRevision.Range.Rows(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString 
but got the error for vertically merged cells. 
How can I get the revision text and step number for any cell in the table?

```
Dim oRange As Range
Dim oRevision As Revision
Dim strText As String
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long

For Each oRevision In oDoc.Revisions
    Select Case oRevision.Type
        'Only include insertions and deletions
        Case wdRevisionInsert, wdRevisionDelete
            'In case of footnote/endnote references (appear as Chr(2)),
            'insert "[footnote reference]"/"[endnote reference]"
            With oRevision
                'Get the changed text
                strText = .Range.Text

stepnumber = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString

If oRevision.Range.Rows(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString = "" Then
oRevision.Range.Select
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdRow
stepnumber = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString

ElseIf oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString = "" Then
Do
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Loop Until oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString <> ""
stepnumber = oRevision.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
End If

                End With
            'Add 1 to counter
            n = n + 1
            'Add row to table
            Set oRow = oTable.Rows.Add

            'Insert data in cells in oRow
            With oRow


                'SECTION
                    .Cells(1).Range.Text = _
                    "Step " & stepnumber

                'Type of revision
                If oRevision.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
                    .Cells(2).Range.Text = "Inserted: " & strText
                    .Range.Font.Bold = False

                Else
                    .Cells(2).Range.Text = "Deleted: " & strText
                    .Range.Font.Bold = False
                End If

            End With
    End Select
Next oRevision
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Table.Cell(r, c)` approach to get around your merged cells issue:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, rev As Revision, c As Cell
    Dim rownum As Long

    For Each rev In ThisDocument.Revisions

        Set rng = rev.Range
        rng.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart

        If rng.Information(wdWithInTable) Then

            rownum = rng.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)

            Set c = rng.Tables(1).Cell(rownum, 1) 'first cell on the row

            Debug.Print c.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString

        End If
    Next rev

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much. Do you have any ideas on how to select a cell above the revision in case there isn't a step number at the beginning of the row?

Comment: If you need the cell above then   `Set c = rng.Tables(1).Cell(rownum-1, 1)` should do it.  With a check you're not already on the first row....

Comment: Oh duuuuuhhh. Thanks a bunch.